# Optimizing a value based search algorithm with LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, algorithm, linq

I want to build a value based search algorithm. What this means is that once I'm given a list of words I would like to search for entries on the database using those words. However depending on what column/property those words match, I want to alter the value of results returned.

Here is a lazy algorithm that achieves that but is very slow.

```
//search only active entries
var query = (from a in db.Jobs where a.StatusId == 7 select a);
List<SearchResult> baseResult = new List<SearchResult>();
foreach (var item in search)
            {
               //if the company title is matched, results are worth 5 points
                var companyMatches = (from a in query where a.Company.Name.ToLower().Contains(item.ToLower()) select new SearchResult() { ID = a.ID, Value = 5 });

                //if the title is matched results are worth 3 points
                var titleMatches = (from a in query where a.Title.ToLower().Contains(item.ToLower()) select new SearchResult() { ID = a.ID, Value = 3 });

                //if text within the body is matched results are worth 2 points
                var bodyMatches = (from a in query where a.FullDescription.ToLower().Contains(item.ToLower()) select new SearchResult() { ID = a.ID, Value = 2 });


                 //all results are then added 
                baseResult = baseResult.Concat(companyMatches.Concat(titleMatches).Concat(bodyMatches)).ToList();
            }

              // the value gained for each entry is then added and sorted by highest to lowest
            List<SearchResult> result = baseResult.GroupBy(x => x.ID).Select(p => new SearchResult() { ID = p.First().ID, Value = p.Sum(i => i.Value) }).OrderByDescending(a => a.Value).ToList<SearchResult>();

            //the query for the complete result set is built based on the sorted id value of result
            query = (from id in result join jbs in db.Jobs on id.ID equals jbs.ID select jbs).AsQueryable();
```

I'm looking for ways to optimize this. I am new to LINQ query so I was hoping I could get some help. If there is away I can create the LINQ query that achieves all of this in one go instead of checking for company name and then title and the body text and bringing it all together and creating a sorted list and running it again against the database to get full listing it would be great.

Comment: I suspect your primary time sink is querying the database three different times. Is your data small enough that you can load the entire data set into memory and then do in-memory queries?

Comment: 3000 entries with the FullDescription portion ranging between 1000 to 5000 character. It's not super heavy but it's not light either. I'm looking to create one query that does what the three different queries do or perhaps venture into Stored Procedures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best if I study the problem first. My previous answer was optimizing the wrong thing. The primary problem here is going over the results list multiple times. We can change that:

```
foreach (var a in query)
{
    foreach (var item in search)
    {
        itemLower = item.ToLower();
        int val = 0;
        if (a.Company.Name.ToLower.Contains(itemLower))
            baseResult.Add(new SearchResult { ID = a.ID, Value = 5});
        if (a.Title.ToLower.Contains(itemLower))
            baseResult.Add(new SearchResult { ID = a.ID, Value = 3});
        if (a.FullDescription.ToLower().Contains(itemLower))
            baseResult.Add(new SearchResult { ID = a.ID, Value = 2});
    }
}
```

After that, you have your base result and you can continue with your processing.

That reduces it to a single query rather than three queries for each search item.

I wasn't sure if you wanted unique items in your `baseResult`, or if there was some reason you allowed duplicates and then used the sum of the values to order them. If you want unique items, you could make `baseResult` a `Dictionary`, with the ID as the key.

### Edit after comment

You could reduce the number of items in the list by doing:

```
int val = 0;
if (a.Company.Name.ToLower.Contains(itemLower))
    val += 5;
if (a.Title.ToLower.Contains(itemLower))
    val += 3;
if (a.FullDescription.ToLower().Contains(itemLower))
    val += 2;
if (val > 0)
{
    baseResult.Add(new SearchResult { ID = a.ID, Value = val });
}
```

That won't eliminate duplicates altogether, though, because the company name could match one search term, and the title might match another search term. But it would reduce the list somewhat.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, I'll give it a try and let you know. Thank you

Comment: I allow duplicates so all the points are added at the end and results with the highest points are pushed to the top. So if a search term matches a company name and title it shows up twice, and when added ends up with the total value of 8 which makes it more relevant than those which only matched either only company name or only title.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jim's answer and some tweeking on my side I managed to reduce the time it takes to complete the search by 80%

Here is the final solution:

```
 //establish initial query
 var queryBase = (from a in db.Jobs where a.StatusId == 7 select a);

//instead of running the search against all of the entities, I first take the ones that are possible candidates, this is done through checking if they have any of the search terms under any of their columns. This is the one and only query that will be run against the database
if (search.Count > 0)
        {

            nquery = nquery.Where(job => search.All(y => (job.Title.ToLower() + " " + job.FullDescription.ToLower() + " " + job.Company.Name.ToLower() + " " + job.NormalLocation.ToLower() + " " + job.MainCategory.Name.ToLower() + " " + job.JobType.Type.ToLower()).Contains(y))); //  + " " + job.Location.ToLower() + " " + job.MainCategory.Name.ToLower() + " " + job.JobType.Type.ToLower().Contains(y)));
        }

        //run the query and grab a list of baseJobs
        List<Job> baseJobs = nquery.ToList<Job>();

        //A list of SearchResult object (these object act as a container for job ids       and their search values
        List<SearchResult> baseResult = new List<SearchResult>();

        //from here on Jim's algorithm comes to play where it assigns points depending on where the search term is located and added to a list of id/value pair list
        foreach (var a in baseJobs)
        {
            foreach (var item in search)
            {
                var itemLower = item.ToLower();

                if (a.Company.Name.ToLower().Contains(itemLower))
                    baseResult.Add(new SearchResult { ID = a.ID, Value = 5 });
                if (a.Title.ToLower().Contains(itemLower))
                    baseResult.Add(new SearchResult { ID = a.ID, Value = 3 });
                if (a.FullDescription.ToLower().Contains(itemLower))
                    baseResult.Add(new SearchResult { ID = a.ID, Value = 2 });
            }
        }

        List<SearchResult> result = baseResult.GroupBy(x => x.ID).Select(p => new SearchResult() { ID = p.First().ID, Value = p.Sum(i => i.Value) }).OrderByDescending(a => a.Value).ToList<SearchResult>();

        //the data generated through the id/value pair list are then used to reorder the initial jobs.
        var NewQuery = (from id in result join jbs in baseJobs on id.ID equals jbs.ID select jbs).AsQueryable();
```